# tar a directory

Tags: tar

```
#!/bin/bash

current_date=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
file="name Backup ($current_date)"
tar -cvzf $file.tgz module8
```

My output needs to be named "name Backup $current_date"

When I run the script is just names the file "name" not even "name.tgz"

This is what I get for an output

name                 | 175 kB | 175.0 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%

Backup: No such file or directory

(03-16-2019).tgz: No such file or directory

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 2):

The tar command receives the variable contents as whitespace separated list of arguments. You do not want that, you need to quote them:

```
tar -cvzf "$file.tgz" module8
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured out what I was doing wrong...
Line 4 needed to be `file="name Backup ($current_date).tgz"`
Line 5 needed to be `tar -cvzf "$file" module8`